# AWS CloudFront - how to serve multiple origins with single CloudFront and SSL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I have following scenario -

1. Setup S3 bucket to host static website, I've successfully deployed react app in this bucket.
2. Setup EC2 instance for APIs developed in JAVA.
3. For authentication from react app, AWS cognito is integrated.

Domain and SSL is purchased from Godaddy.

I want to run both S3 and EC2 origins from single domain (with SSL) through cloudfront.

My front end react app i.e. S3 origin is working fine with cloud front, but when I try to access API through it, it throws following error -

[image]

Can anyone please help!!

Comment: Have you configured your Cloudfront distribution correctly? First import your certificate to ACM, then set your distribution to use this certificate. A detailed troubleshooting guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/http-502-bad-gateway.html

Comment: It's not the certificate used on distribution, it's when cloudfront connects go origin over https, in this case cloudfront works like a browser and it checks if cert presented by origin: trusted, not expired, matches common name of cert with SNI,  check whats the origin domain name you have defined in cloudfront and it should match with the certificate's common name provided by origin + cloudfront also serves 502 if it receives reset from origin.

Comment: @erhanux - Yes I have imported SSL to ACM first, please let me know is there any specific settings you want to check?

Comment: @JamesDean - what should be the settings to run it, please assist

Comment: Have you config different "Path pattern" in Behavior tab for your API server?

Comment: @DominicNguyen - Yes I have configured it. I am almost there, I can access back end API with cloudfront url but not with my custom domain, any idea?